# Pass the value of dropdownlist item to another page as a query string

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display/redirect the selected values of the drop down lists from a HTML page to a new page. The codes are unable to be executed. Need help on this one (using javascript).

These are the codes of 'mainTest.html' file. I've encountered failure in redirecting the page to another HTML page.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  (function() {
    /**
     * Handles the click of the submit button.
     */
    function onSubmitClicked(event) {
      // Get the input element from the DOM.
      var beverage = document.getElementById('foodbeverage'),
        // Get the value from the element.
        beverageValue = beverage.value,
        // Construct the URL.
        url = 'newPageTest.html?foodbeverage=' + encodeURIComponent(beverageValue) + '&status=' + encodeURIComponent(status);

      // Instead of going to the URL, log it to the console.
      console.log('goto to URL: ', url);
    }

    // Get the button from the DOM.
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('btngo');
    // Add an event listener for the click event.
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', onSubmitClicked);
  })(); <
/script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div align="center"></div>

  <center>
    <h4 style="color:darkblue">Choose Your Food/Beverage & Quantity : </h3>
  </center>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <font size=2>
          <B>Choose a Food/Beverage : </B>
        </font>

        <select ID="foodbeverage"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Food">
 <option value = "chickenchop">Chicken Chop</option>
 <option value = "pasta">Pasta</option>
 <option value = "pizza">Pizza</option>
 <option value = "chocolate">Chocolate Cake</option>
 <option value = "redvelvet">Red Velvet Cake</option>
 <option value = "icecream">Ice Cream Cake</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Beverages">
 <option value = "milk">Milk</option>
 <option value = "freshjuice">Fresh Juice</option>
 <option value = "icecream">Ice Cream</option>
 <option value = "coffee">Coffee</option>
 <option value = "carbonated">Carbonated Can Drink</option>
 <option value = "water">Water</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 </select>
        <br/>

        <font size=2>
          <B>Choose a Food/Beverage : </B>
        </font>

        <select ID="foodbeverage1"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Food">
 <option value = "chickenchop">Chicken Chop</option>
 <option value = "pasta">Pasta</option>
 <option value = "pizza">Pizza</option>
 <option value = "chocolate">Chocolate Cake</option>
 <option value = "redvelvet">Red Velvet Cake</option>
 <option value = "icecream">Ice Cream Cake</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="Beverages">
 <option value = "milk">Milk</option>
 <option value = "freshjuice">Fresh Juice</option>
 <option value = "icecream">Ice Cream</option>
 <option value = "coffee">Coffee</option>
 <option value = "carbonated">Carbonated Can Drink</option>
 <option value = "water">Water</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 </select>
        <br/>

      </td>

      <td>
        <font size=2>
          <B>Dine In or Take Away : </B>
        </font>
        <select ID="status"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="STATUS">
 <option value = "dinein">Dine In</option>
 <option value = "takeaway">Take Away</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
        <br/>

        <font size=2>
          <B>Dine In or Take Away : </B>
        </font>
        <select ID="status1"> 
 
 <optgroup label="DEFAULT">
 <option value = "NONE">NONE</option>
 </optgroup>
 
 <optgroup label="STATUS">
 <option value = "dinein">Dine In</option>
 <option value = "takeaway">Take Away</option>
 </optgroup>
 </select>
        <br/>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <br/>
  <br/>

  <input type="submit" id="btngo" value="Go" />

  <br/>
</body>

</html>
```

These are the codes of 'newPageTest.html' file where the drop down values selected will be displayed.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  window.onload = passParameters;

//Function to update "showdata" div with URL Querystring parameter values
function passParameters() {
  var foodbeverage = getParameterByName("foodbeverage");
  var status = getParameterByName("status");
  if (foodbeverage != null && status != null) {
    var data = "<b>Food Beverages:</b> " + foodbeverage + " <b>Dine Takeaway:</b> " + status;
    document.getElementById("showdata").innerHTML = data;
  }
}
//Get URL parameter value
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
} <
/script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <div id="showdata" align="center"></div>
  <font size=6>
    <B>Food/Beverage Selected : </B>
  </font>

  <br/>
  <br/>

  <font size=6>
    <B>Dine In/Take Away : </B>
  </font>

  <br/>
  <br/>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you even read the code? I made the method in the first snippet in  your previous question and the code comment even says there is no redirect happening. You just copied and pasted it without looking at it.

Comment: @Thijs So sorry, I did as what you said, still fail to redirect, these are the original codes which was done by you. I guess the problem is somewhere else. I tried to put in <form> i between the button codes, the page redirected but no values are being referred. I couldn't figure the out where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onSubmitClicked` method you need to:

- Get the status element, just like the element for the beverages is retrieved from the DOM
- Get the value of the status element before you try to use it in the `encodeURIComponent(status)`
- Where the `console.log` line, replace that code with code that will alter the URL.

For the second page:

- Don't use `font` tags, use CSS instead.
- Assign ids to the elements you want to show the beverage and status text in
- Retrieve the elements from DOM like in the `onSubmitClicked` method
- Once you have the elements, you can do `myElement.textContent = <text>` to show the value in your page.

Comment: Do I need to create an array to display the second row of drop down list? Do I need to assign unique ID for each drop down list?

Comment: If I were you, I would first try to get it to work with a single foodbeverage and status select. Once you have that, try expanding to multiple orders.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not redirect anywhere. You have to add `location.href = url;` after this line

```
url = 'newPageTest.html?foodbeverage=' + encodeURIComponent(beverageValue) + '&status=' + encodeURIComponent(status);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Realized that I need to change the console.log